# Insert method with concatenation in a HashTable in C

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

I have a problem in implementing the insert method for a Hash Table in C. The following lines of code briefly outlines the structure of my program:

```
struct someStruct{
    struct someStruct *next;
};

typedef struct someStruct Ele;

typedef struct someStruct *EleP;

typedef EleP HTEntry;

struct symbolTable {
    HTEntry hashTable[CON];
};
```

In my program the hashTable is enclosed in other two data structures that I think are not important for this description, the only important thing is that to access to the hashTable I need to do as follow:

```
Var->anotherVar->hashTable
```

Given the definitions above, my problem is that when I try to insert an element into the hashTable it seems that I am not using pointers and the modifications have not any kind of reflection in the memory. If I do the following it works:

```
EleP toAdd = [...]
Var->anotherVar->hashTable[key] = toAdd;
```

That works fine, however, if I want to concatenate any new element with the old one I am not able to reflect the changes in the memory, it seems that I am copying the value and not the reference. Here the code:

```
HTEntry w = Var->anotherVar->hashTable[key];
while(w != NULL){
    w = w->next;
}
w = toAdd;
```

If I try to print the value of w inside the function that performs the insertion I get the correct element, but when the function returns the value is not in the table. I am trying to figure out where there is the missing pointer but I have really no idea.

EDIT:
The solution proposed by Eyal actually allows to add elements to the hastTable, however, the elements are added to key+5 and not to key. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. You are setting w (which is now NULL) to toAdd. You should be setting the previous element's `w->next = toAdd`

Try

```
HTEntry w = Var->anotherVar->hashTable[key];
while(w != NULL && w->next != NULL){
    w = w->next;
}
if (w != NULL) w->next = toAdd;
```

Comment: It works, but it seems that is adding the element 5 cell after: I mean, if the key is 2 the element is added to key=7